# what server role that needs to be configured for the user to enable sql server agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, users, sql-server-agent

I'm on SQL SERVER 2008,

I want to enable the SQL Agent for a particular user, who has only read access to the database. I don't want to give sysadmin role?

Is there any way, I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "enable SQL Agent for a user"? Allow them to create jobs? Allow them to execute jobs but not create them? Read access to which database?

Comment: Yes, Allow them to create and execute the jobs. The user has read access to the specific db created in the server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283.aspx) :

> To configure a user to create or execute Microsoft SQL Server Agent jobs, you must first add an existing SQL Server login or msdb role to one of the following SQL Server Agent fixed database roles in the msdb database: SQLAgentUserRole, SQLAgentReaderRole, or SQLAgentOperatorRole.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187901.aspx , it explains how to add the SQLAgent roles to the non-admin user